# Read/Write Complex Object in CoreData & Maintain Query-ability?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

## Problem Description

I have a complex object that I need to store in CoreData. The object has fields which are themselves objects, etc. Here is the main object:

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
    let opportunityID: HOV_String
    let displayName: HOV_String
    let displayUnit: HOV_String
    let opportunityPoints: HOV_Float
    let date_SatisfyingEvent: HOV_Date
    let opportunityAchieved: HOV_Bool
    let opportunityMissed: HOV_Bool
    let didUserActivate: HOV_Bool
    let didUserDismiss: HOV_Bool
    let evaluationType: HOV_String
    let deleteOnReconfigure: HOV_Bool
    let dataType: HOV_String
    let dataTypeType: HOV_String
    let tolerance: HOV_Float
    let availableTapDest: HOV_String
    let availableTapDestType: HOV_String
    let achievedTapDest: HOV_String
    let achievedTapDestType: HOV_String
    let missedTapDest: HOV_String
    let missedTapDestType: HOV_String
    let isBlurable: HOV_Bool
    
    let userid: String
    let date_Saved: Date?
    var date_Acknowledgement: Date?
    var acknowledgementStatus: Int
    
    let hkid: String
    var buildNo: Int
    var releaseVersion: String
    var timeZone: String
    let date_Created: Date?

    ...
    //Some Initializers...
}
```

You'll notice the custom types, each prefixed with the 'HOV_'. These variables are all composed the same, as a structure with an optional version of the corresponding type and one other **UpdateMetaData** field. For example, the **HOV_Bool** type looks like this:

```
struct HOV_Bool: Codable {
    var value: Bool?
    let updateData: UpdateMetaData
    
    init(val: Bool? = nil, time: Date? = Date()) {
        value = val
        updateData = UpdateMetaData(time: time)
    }
}
```

The **UpdateMetaData** is also a struct with several parameters, as shown here:

```
struct UpdateMetaData: Codable {
    var lastUpdated: Date?
    var enforceUpdate: Bool?
    var freezeValue: Bool?
    
    init(time: Date? = Date()) {
        lastUpdated = time
        enforceUpdate = false
        freezeValue = false
    }
}
```

You will notice that each structure and sub-structure are all conforming to the Codable Protocol. This is because this structure is also passed back and forth between my server and client, and this allows it to be easily transformed into a JSON object for that purpose.
However, I DO NOT want to simply serialize MyObject and store it to CoreData or elsewhere as a Data object because this would make it unable to be queried by its parameters. In the very least, I need MyObject to be queryable in CoreData by the **date_Created** parameter.

## Posed Solution

I THINK that a potential solution would be to convert MyObject to a version of itself where all of the non-native types (all of the 'HOV_' type parameters) were converted to Data (this leaves some of the important metadata fields like the **date_Created** field as is) and simply have a CoreData entity that looks exactly like the MyObject description above where those fields are marked as **Transformable**. Then when I read from CoreData, is simply pack the serialized info back into the MyObject struct.

EVEN IF this is the best solution, I am still a little fuzzy on how to implement this and would seriously love some explanation to that aspect. If there is a better way or even an industry standard for a circumstance like this, please let me know.

## Related Questions

While searching for answers to this problem I ran into a few questions I thought may be relevant so I will link them here:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741847/how-to-save-a-dictionary-to-core-data-in-swift) is roughly a more basic version of my problem. One answer mentions creating other entities and then creating 1-many relationships between them. I don't think I want this approach because that is better suited for arrays of complex sub-structures, and I would end up basically making a new entity for every field I have defined with 'HOV_'. The second answer here mentions serializing the entire object (which I cannot do), but is what got me thinking about the potential solution I posed.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson 
Could you elaborate a bit more on these computed properties? Or point me in the direction of some documentation (or better yet, an example please) of using this for my purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure of a complete solution but one critical detail is that `Codable` does not work with transformable properties. You need to use `NSCoding`, which is similar to but not compatible with `Codable`. And it's difficult or impossible to use `NSCoding` with a struct-- you really need a class that inherits from `NSObject`. Using transformable might be a lot more refactoring than it seems like at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** is to create Entities for all the types and those entities would be individually `Codable`

https://www.donnywals.com/using-codable-with-core-data-and-nsmanagedobject/

And then decode and encode with standard methods.

**Option 2** is to create a "HolderEntity" that would use `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` to transform to and from `MyObject`, it is quite "easy" in a way but it does require that `MyObject` and subtypes be a `class`

[How to delete and update structure type array in Core Data iOS Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153791/how-to-delete-and-update-structure-type-array-in-core-data-ios-swift/69335920#69335920)

**Option 3** is to create a "HolderEntity" with a `myModelJSON: String?` and save the whole thing as a JSON.

```
extension HolderEntity{
    var myObject: MyObject?{
        get{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let obj = try? decoder.decode(MyObject.self, from: self.myModelJSON?.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()) {
                return obj
            }else{
                return nil
            }
        }
        set{
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(newValue) {
                self.myModelJSON = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All 3 offer different advantages/disadvatages with the first one being the one that allows you to use all the CoreData features to the third been the quickest to implement but the slowest and most precarious.

As far as your proposed solution

`Transformable` types, require or will soon require `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` (it been in warnings for years), you need classes for this (not a struct), the link in Option 2 shows you how to pursue this option and you will need a transformer for each type. This will require at the same or more work than option 1 where you make Entities for everything and them make them Codable.

Comment: Thank you so much @lorem_ipsum this has been a fantastic starting point with good information. If you could edit your answer in option 1 section to link to an example and/or describe a bit more about exactly how to set up the multiple entities, I think this answer would be more complete and I'd be happy to grant bounty and approved answer. Thanks again for the good info.

Comment: @jcodes the Donny Walls link is as good as it gets for an example. I provided code for the “quick” solution.

Comment: Very well, I will mark the answer as it is. For anyone else maybe needing a tad of clarity for the entity set up in CoreData, this archived documentation was a bit useful: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1